# running python executable from windows command line with arguments

Tags: python, windows

I am using the windows7 command prompt and have opened the python interpreter and changed to the directory where the file is located.  The instructions I have say to get into the directory and type

`./keyboardControl.py 192.168.1.108`

where keyboardControl.py is the name of the file and the ip address is for a robot.

I get the error:

*File "", line 1
.\keyboardControl.py 192.168.1.108
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
(with the carrot under the . before )

I have also tried:

`python keyboardControl.py 192.168.1.108`

I get the same error with the carrot now under the l in Control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've launched the Python interpreter and are typing these commands into the REPL. This is not what you should be doing. The commands should be run directly at the `cmd` prompt, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\me>keyboardControl.py 192.168.1.108
```

If that does not work (file associations might not be set correctly - Windows does not handle the `#!` "shebang") the form would be.

```
C:\Users\me>python keyboardControl.py 192.168.1.108
```

Comment: @user3687879 on Stack Overflow, the way you indicate that an answer helped you is actually by accepting it (clicking the green check box to the left of the question) instead of leaving comments thanking the user who answered.